# having trouble changing Js variable to user input value from <input>

Tags: javascript, html, forms

There is a user input field in an HTML form. My intention is for the user's inputed value to become the value of the variable 'price'. I have been unable to figure out how to do this. Can someone please steer me in the right direction.

```js
// Variables
const button = document.getElementById('button');
const returnChange = document.getElementById('return-change');
const returnStatus = document.getElementById('return-status');
const cid = [
  ['PENNY', 1.01],
  ['NICKEL', 2.05],
  ['DIME', 3.1],
  ['QUARTER', 4.25],
  ['ONE', 90],
  ['FIVE', 55],
  ['TEN', 20],
  ['TWENTY', 60],
  ['ONE HUNDRED', 100]
];

let cash = document.getElementById('payment');
let price = document.getElementById('price').value;


  console.log(price);
  console.log(cash);
  console.log(cid);
```

```html
        <div id="price-div">
            <form>
                <label for="price" >Purchase Price:
                    <input id='price' name='price' type="number" required />
                </label>
            </form>
        </div>

        <div id="payment-div">
            <label for="payment"> Payment Amount:
                <input id='payment' type="number" required />
            </label>
        </div>
        <div id="button-div">
            <button id="button" type="button" >Return Change</button>
        </div>
        <div id="change">
            <p id="return-change"></p>
            <p id="return-status"></p>
        </div>
```

Comment: Use `.value` to get the value of the input. `document.getElementById('price').value`

Comment: What does this do isntead of the expected result? I don't think forms have an [change](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event) event.

Comment: @mykaf The change event bubbles up from the input.

Comment: currently if I enter a number into the input field, and cosole.log(price), the console returns <input id='price' name='price' type="number" required />. if I use document.getElementById('price').value , the console returns nothing (a blank line)

Comment: Can you add the logging code to your post?

Comment: @mykaf I hope this is what your'e asking for, I don't have the best coding verbiage. console.log(price); <input id="price" name="price" type="number" required="">

Comment: please feel free to look at my entire code if youd like https://github.com/aaronnwg/Cash-Register

Comment: Please include a minimal reproducible example in your original post. Links to outside resources can break so future readers can't access them. Context is so important; we don't know when/how you are logging the price.

Comment: In the `checkCashRegister()` function, use `price.value` and `cash.value`.

Comment: @mykaf sorry i'm a new learner and am very confused. I dont understand what you are asking me to provide. as far as I know, none of my other code is relevant to this issue. I appreciate your patience.

Comment: You said you are logging it, but your code here does not show any logging. Your code here doesn't match your github, and we should not have to sort through your github to figure out what's going on anyway. Where in your code do you call `console.log()`? When does that get executed? Where and how are you using `price`? In this case, it's scoped to `getValue()`, so you will not be able to use it elsewhere.

Comment: @mykaf sorry my commits were not up to date, and my code was very messy because of all the troubleshooting. Im still learning all the basics, so i do apologize if im difficult to help. I have updated my code up top to be exactly what youd see in my text editor. I separated all irrelevant code into a separate module, so the only interaction should be between the inputs and the variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to use an [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener):

```js
const priceInput = document.getElementById("price");
const priceHandler = e => {
  price = e.target.value;
  console.log(price);
};
priceInput.addEventListener('input', priceHandler);
```

```html
<form>
  <label for="price">Purchase Price:
           <input id='price' name='price' type="number" required />
       </label>
</form>
```

Comment: I just tried this, and unfortunately it doesnt change anything.

Comment: What did you try ? If you run the code snippet I've just posted and type any number in the price field, you'll see that it works fine. Perhaps the variable names are different in your code ?

Comment: I'm glad I could helped you. Could you upvote and mark this answer as "accepted" (by clicking the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in), so that it gets tagged as resolved ?

Answer (score -1):

We need a little more detail on what you are seeing happen when you try the above.  However, looking at the code, some suggestions:

1. You don't need the 'return getValue()'. getValue() alone is fine.
2. You can get the value from the element returned

```js
function getValue() {
  let element = document.getElementById("price");
  let value = element.value;
  console.log(value)
}
```

```html
<form onchange="getValue()">
  <label for="price">Purchase Price:
       <input id='price' name='price' type="number" required />
   </label>
</form>
```